# adb logcat cannot write to file using -f option (under windows XP)

Tags: android, windows, file, windows-xp, logcat

I want to write log from my android device to the file under Windows XP. 
I'm trying to use command:

```
adb logcat -f test
```

But it returns:

```
log file locked.couldn't open output file: Bad file number
```

If I use

```
adb logcat >test
```

then it works OK, but it doesn't show anything to the console. 
I thought that using "-f" option would show data in console and simultaneously write to the file. 
How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing in case someone fall here.

The `-f` options expects a path from phone folder (and not from your PC). For example:

```
adb logcat -f /sdcard/test.txt
```

Then, after stopping the log, you must pull that file from phone:

```
adb pull /sdcard/test.txt
```